# Discord.js v12 giveaway command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so basically I have this giveaway command which works good but if u react with the emoji after the time u set is done it will just send "Not enough people reacted for me to draw a winner it won't pick the winner" Idk why this is happening.

```
client.on('message', async message =>{
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'giveaway')) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) 
return message.channel.send('You cant use this command sice youre missing `manage_messages` perm')
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ")
    let time = args[1]
    if(!time) return message.channel.send('You did not specify your time');
    if(
      !args[1].endsWith("d") &&
      !args[1].endsWith("h") &&
      !args[1].endsWith("m") &&
      !args[1].endsWith("s")
    )
    return message.channel.send("You need to use d (days), h (hours), m (minutes), or s (seconds)")

    let gchannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    if(!gchannel) return message.channel.send("I cant find that channel in the server.")
    let prize = args.slice(3).join(" ")
    if(!prize) return message.channel.send('What is the prize?')

    message.delete()
    gchannel.send(`:tada: **New Giveaway** :tada:`)
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('New Giveaway')
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription(`React with :tada: to enter the giveaway. 
\nHosted By: **${message.author}** \nTime: **${time}**\nPrize: **${prize}**`)
    .setFooter(`Will end in ${time}`)
    let reaction = await gchannel.send(newEmbed)
    reaction.react("")
    setTimeout(() => {
      if ((m) => m.reaction.cache.get("").count <= 0) {
        return message.channel.send("Not enough people reacted for me to draw a winner")
      }
      let winner = (m) => m.reaction.cache.get("").users.cache.filter((u) => !u.bot).random();
      gchannel.send(`Congratulations ${winner} You just won the **${prize}**!`
      );
    }, ms(args[1]));
  }
})
```

Comment: Where does `m` come from? You can't do that. You need to get the actual message object with the reactions on it (`reaction`)

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You already have it in the `reaction` variable

Comment: idk what to change or what to change it instead

Comment: Well `.send()` returns a promise that contains a Message object, which has the property `reactions` on it

Comment: so do I need to add that send? if so where?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an arrow function for no reason on your if statement, as `m` has not been set to anything, you will get `undefined`.

To fix this, you need to use the message you send as your Message object, as when you use `.send()` a promise is returned, which contains a [Message](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. This object then has the property `reactions` which can be used to get the reactions on the message.

For example:

```js
if (reaction.reactions.cache.get("").count <= 0) {
    return message.channel.send("Not enough people reacted for me to draw a winner")
}
```

However, I would suggest using a [ReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector) instead as you can setup a filter and a time and then an event will be fired off instead, which you can listen to and get the size of etc.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '';
};

const collector = reaction.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
// time is in ms (so 15000ms is 15 seconds)

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected  from ${user.tag}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    // collected.size will only contain the number of  on the message, as the collector had a filter applied to it
});
```